# Python Pandas - Rolling regressions for multiple columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I have a large dataframe containing daily timeseries of prices for 10,000 columns (stocks) over a period of 20 years (5000 rows x 10000 columns). Missing observations are indicated by NaNs.

```
            0      1      2      3      4      5       6      7      8      \
31.12.2009  30.75  66.99    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN  393.87  57.04    NaN   
01.01.2010  30.75  66.99    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN  393.87  57.04    NaN   
04.01.2010  31.85  66.99    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN  404.93  57.04    NaN   
05.01.2010  33.26  66.99    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN  400.00  58.75    NaN   
06.01.2010  33.26  66.99    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN  400.00  58.75    NaN
```

Now I want to run a rolling regression for a 250 day window for each column over the whole sample period and save the coefficient in another dataframe

Iterating over the colums and rows using two for-loops isn't very efficient, so I tried this but getting the following error message

```
def regress(start, end):
    y = df_returns.iloc[start:end].values

    if np.isnan(y).any() == False:
        X = np.arange(len(y))
        X = sm.add_constant(X, has_constant="add")
        model = sm.OLS(y,X).fit()

        return model.params[1]

    else:
        return np.nan


regression_window = 250

for t in (regression_window, len(df_returns.index)):

    df_coef[t] = df_returns.apply(regress(t-regression_window, t), axis=1)
```

```
TypeError: ("'float' object is not callable", 'occurred at index 31.12.2009')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is my version, using df.rolling() instead and iterating over the columns. 
I am not completely sure it is what you were looking for don't hesitate to comment

```py
import statsmodels.regression.linear_model as sm
import statsmodels.tools.tools as sm2
df_returns =pd.DataFrame({'0':[30,30,31,32,32],'1':[60,60,60,60,60],'2':[np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN]})


def regress(X,Z):

    if np.isnan(X).any() == False:
        model = sm.OLS(X,Z).fit()        
        return model.params[1]

    else:
        return np.NaN


regression_window = 3
Z = np.arange(regression_window)
Z= sm2.add_constant(Z, has_constant="add")
df_coef=pd.DataFrame()
for col in df_returns.columns:
    df_coef[col]=df_returns[col].rolling(window=regression_window).apply(lambda col : regress(col, Z))
df_coef
```

Comment: This works pretty neat - thank you! Any suggestions how to further bump up the speed?

Comment: Don't hesitate to validate/upvote the question if it fits your needs. To speed up you can delete the print() statements and take out the lines `Z = np.arange(len(X))` and `Z= sm2.add_constant(Z, has_constant="add")` of the function and pass Z as a parameter of the regress function as the size of X won't change

Comment: Your edits helped to speed up the computation by 26% - awesome! Did vote up/validate your answer, not sure if it gets displayed as I dont have a stackoverflow reputation of 15 (just started)

Comment: Glad I helped, yes the answer is validated